# Trying to export and import a vue component into another component which isnt the App.vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

First of all -

I have created a Hamburger.vue in the components directory, secondly I wanted to import this hamburger into my Header.vue file so I dont have to repeat the code.

I will attach a playground code with the code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-tailwind-playground-forked-0016sh?file=/src/App.vue

I have no idea what it is, as I've checked multiple times its the right file path or am I just doing this incorrectly?

I was hoping for the Hamburger menu to appear in the navigation bar, without having to stick every single component in the App.vue file (as this is the only way I can get things to work using export default {} ).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: please include [mcve] in the OP itself

Comment: Hi, I dont mean to be rude but Ive attached a link with the example of the code and how i've got it structured on my local environment?

Comment: SO doesn't control external links, so can't moderate what is contained or if the link exists. If your link dies or is deleted, this question becomes undetailed/unhelpful

Answer (score 3):

If using the Options API, components have to be registered in the same component you import them into. See the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#using-a-component)

**Header.vue**

```js
import Hamburger from "@/components/Hamburger.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Hamburger,
  },
}
```

The self-registration should also be removed from the Hamburger.vue component

[updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-tailwind-playground-forked-sz7mpr?file=/src/components/Header.vue)

Comment: Hi thank you for your help, I can get it working in the sandbox and on the one I was using previously! But when I make the exact changes in my IDE it just comes up with a white screen and nothing gets outputted in the <div id='app'>. Im using vite, is there any dependencies I need to install with npm e.c.t?

Comment: double check the paths on your imports are correct.  I recommend using the "@" as shorthand alias for "./src". which is what I used in the sandbox. The alias should be defined that way by default in new vue + vite projects, but you can verify your `vite.config.js` matches [this](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/import-aliases-in-vite/)